# Docker SystemD require another container first

Tags: systemd, boot, docker

I control all my Docker containers via systemd. Everything works correctly but I found out that after reboot one of my container doesn't work correctly because another container hasn't booted yet.

What would be the best/proper way to have docker container B not boot until container A is booted?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I control both conatiners via systemd, i just added a "wants" `container.service`, but that didn't end up working as it needed the service to be fully running before starting. I just used a cron reboot script to